# Installing hive on ubuntu (trouble with derby ?)

Tags: java, linux, apache-spark, hive, ubuntu-16.04

I've installed Hadoop, Spark, R, Rstudio-server and SparkR, and I'm now trying to install Hive.

Following tutorials on the internet, here's what I did :

```
$ cd /home/francois-ubuntu/media/
$ mkdir install-hive
$ cd install-hive
$ wget http://mirrors.ircam.fr/pub/apache/hive/hive-2.1.0/apache-hive-2.1.0-bin.tar.gz
$ tar -xzvf apache-hive-2.1.0-bin.tar.gz
$ mkdir /usr/lib/hive
$ mv apache-hive-2.1.0-bin /usr/lib/hive
$ cd
$ rm -rf /home/francois-ubuntu/media/install-hive
$ sudo vim ~/.bashrc
```

In `.bashrc`, I wrote the following (I'm also including the lines relative to Java, Hadoop and Spark, maybe it can be helpful) :

```
# Set JAVA_HOME
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64

# Set HADOOP_HOME
alias hadoop=/usr/local/hadoop/bin/hadoop
export HADOOP_HOME=/usr/local/hadoop
export PATH=$PATH:$HADOOP_HOME/bin

# Set SPARK_HOME
export SPARK_HOME=/usr/local/spark

# Set HIVE_HOME
export HIVE_HOME=/usr/lib/hive/apache-hive-2.1.0-bin
PATH=$PATH:$HIVE_HOME/bin
export PATH
```

Back to the CLI :

```
$ cd /usr/lib/hive/apache-hive-2.1.0-bin/bin
$ sudo vim hive-config.sh
```

In hive-config.sh, I add :

```
export HADOOP_HOME=/usr/local/hadoop
```

Then `:wq`, back to the CLI :

```
$ hadoop fs -mkdir /usr/hive/warehouse
$ hadoop fs -chmod g+w /usr/hive/warehouse
```

And then finally :

```
$ hive
```

Here is what I get :

```
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/usr/lib/hive/apache-hive-2.1.0-bin/lib/log4j-slf4j-impl-2.4.1.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.10.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [org.apache.logging.slf4j.Log4jLoggerFactory]

Logging initialized using configuration in jar:file:/usr/lib/hive/apache-hive-2.1.0-bin/lib/hive-common-2.1.0.jar!/hive-log4j2.properties Async: true
Mon Jul 18 12:13:44 CEST 2016 Thread[main,5,main] java.io.FileNotFoundException: derby.log (Permission denied)
----------------------------------------------------------------
Mon Jul 18 12:13:45 CEST 2016:
Booting Derby (version The Apache Software Foundation - Apache Derby - 10.10.2.0 - (1582446)) instance a816c00e-0155-fd7f-479a-0000040c9aa0 
on database directory /usr/lib/hive/apache-hive-2.1.0-bin/bin/metastore_db in READ ONLY mode with class loader sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@2e5c649. 
Loaded from file:/usr/lib/hive/apache-hive-2.1.0-bin/lib/derby-10.10.2.0.jar.
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
java.runtime.version=1.8.0_91-8u91-b14-0ubuntu4~16.04.1-b14
user.dir=/usr/lib/hive/apache-hive-2.1.0-bin/bin
os.name=Linux
os.arch=amd64
os.version=4.4.0-28-generic
derby.system.home=null
Database Class Loader started - derby.database.classpath=''
```

And then... nothing, it stops there. According to the tutorials, I should have the hive prompt (`hive>`) at this point, but I don't, I tried some hive commands, they don't work. I don't have the classic CLI prompt either, no prompt, I can type stuff but I can't execute anything. It seems the only thing I can do is stop it with CTRL+C.

Any idea what's wrong ?

Thanks.

---

**Edit 1 :**

Following [this advice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38434236/installing-hive-on-ubuntu-trouble-with-derby/38437488?noredirect=1#comment64282096_38437488) from @Hawknight, I followed the help given [here](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2254028), and did the following :

```
sudo addgroup hive
sudo useradd -g hive hive
sudo adduser hive sudo
sudo mkdir /home/hive
sudo chown -R hive:hive /home/hive
sudo chown -R hive:hive /usr/lib/hive/
visudo
```

Added this line to sudoers file:

```
hive ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL
```

And then, back to CLI :

```
sudo su hive
hive
```

I still get the same problem, though.

---

**Edit 2 :**

Followed the advice from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38434236/installing-hive-on-ubuntu-trouble-with-derby/38437488?noredirect=1#comment64285552_38434236), I now get a different error. The error output is very long, I feel like it might not be useful to copy everything since the other errors probably originate from the first one, so here is the beginning :

```
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/usr/lib/hive/apache-hive-2.1.0-bin/lib/log4j-slf4j-impl-2.4.1.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.10.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [org.apache.logging.slf4j.Log4jLoggerFactory]

Logging initialized using configuration in jar:file:/usr/lib/hive/apache-hive-2.1.0-bin/lib/hive-common-2.1.0.jar!/hive-log4j2.properties Async: true
Mon Jul 18 18:03:44 CEST 2016 Thread[main,5,main] java.io.FileNotFoundException: derby.log (Permission denied)
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.SessionHiveMetaStoreClient
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.session.SessionState.start(SessionState.java:578)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.session.SessionState.beginStart(SessionState.java:518)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.run(CliDriver.java:705)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.main(CliDriver.java:641)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.run(RunJar.java:221)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:136)
Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.SessionHiveMetaStoreClient
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.registerAllFunctionsOnce(Hive.java:226)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.<init>(Hive.java:366)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.create(Hive.java:310)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.getInternal(Hive.java:290)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.get(Hive.java:266)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.session.SessionState.start(SessionState.java:545)
    ... 9 more
```

Please tell me if you want the rest of the error log.

Comment: This shouldn't be the source of the problem, but you don't need to surround the values of your environment properties by double quotes in your `.bashrc` example.

Comment: Edited (the question and my `.bashrc`), thanks.

Comment: Could you try simply with your main user, the one you used during the installation ? (repeating the steps)

Comment: I wasn't sure if you meant "try `hive` or try giving the needed permissions (and then `hive`)", so I did both (in this order), and I still get the same problem.

Comment: If the problem comes from Derby, you might want to give this a shot : http://www.tutorialspoint.com/hive/hive_installation.htm (jump to Derby installation - but by using the latest version of Derby). I'll try to do a clean install of Hive on my Ubuntu laptop.

Comment: Done, see edited answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/117670/discussion-between-hawknight-and-fmalaussena).

Answer (score 1):

The actual SLF4J binding used is Log4j2. For this to work, you need the matching log4j-api and log4j-core dependencies on the classpath. You also need a log4j2.xml configuration in the classpath since the default will only print ERROR messages to the console. The Log4j2 manual has many example configurations.

You may also want to remove slf4j-log4j12-1.7.10.jar from your classpath.

Comment: Waow, let me google all this and come back for questions. In the meantime, thanks I guess :)

Comment: I am not sure this is an issue with log4j, it looks more like an issue with Derby. @fmalaussena Could you try this : https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2254028 ?

Comment: Sure. Do I need to create a new user called `hive`, or should I give these permissions to my main account ?

Comment: It can be better for isolation purposes but you should just try granting them to your main account for the time being.

Comment: Done, please see my edit to the original question. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In mycase, I did something this

```
sudo chown <user_name>:<user_name> /<filepath>/hive
```

eg.

```
sudo chown hduser:hduser /usr/local/hive
```

Lets check by

```
ll -ah /<filepath>/hive
```

Output will be having files with

```
drwxr-xr-x 10 hduser hduser 4.0K Oct 20 01:05 ./
```