# Installing hive on ubuntu (network configuration trouble)

Tags: linux, ubuntu, hadoop, hive, hadoop2

So, as you can see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38434236/installing-hive-on-ubuntu-trouble-with-derby), I'm having troubles installing hive. (Info : Ubuntu 16.04, Java 8, Hadoop 2.7.2, Spark 1.6.2, Hive 2.0.1)

I've solved some of the errors, but now when I try `hive` in my CLI, I'm having the following error:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.net.ConnectException: Call From fma-VirtualBox/127.0.1.1 to localhost:54310 failed on connection exception: java.net.ConnectException: Connexion refusée; For more details see:  http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/ConnectionRefused

I went to link to the Apache Wiki and if I understand well, I think the cause of my problem is explained in this part:

> Quote:
>
> 1. If the error message says the remote service is on "127.0.0.1" or "localhost" that means the configuration file is telling the client that the service is on the local server. If your client is trying to talk to a remote system, then your configuration is broken.
> 2. Check that there isn't an entry for your hostname mapped to 127.0.0.1 or 127.0.1.1 in /etc/hosts (Ubuntu is notorious for this).

So I did `cat /etc/hosts`, and I get:

```
127.0.0.1   localhost
127.0.1.1   fma-VirtualBox

# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1     ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
```

So I think I effectively found the problem. However, I'm not sure how to fix it. Should I just remove the first two lines of `etc/hosts` ? Or edit them to something else ? Or am I wrong in thinking I've found the problem ?

Thanks.

Comment: No one ? I would have thought this was a fairly simple question...

Comment: Can I up this question ?